Image reader throws an Illegal Argument Exception
I am trying to use the Java FX libraries to display the contents of an image file. I don't know why the image reader is throwing an IllegalArgumentException.
package com.mycompany.maven_viscount;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class MyJavaFX extends Application {
  @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws java.io.IOException {
    String path = "C://temp/maven_viscount/image";
    // Create a file
    java.io.PrintWriter dbg = new java.io.PrintWriter(path + "/debug.log");
    dbg.println("debug log open at " + path + "/debug.log");
    dbg.println("viscount picture at " + "image/viscount.gif");
    dbg.flush();
    try {
        Image image = new Image("image/viscount.gif");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        dbg.println(e);
        dbg.flush();
        System.exit(1);
    }
//  irrelevant material  
  }
}

I expected this code to run, but the Image constructor throws an IllegalArgumentException. I am using NetBeans 21. This is the NetBeans directory structure for the maven_viscount project:
maven_viscount
    image
        debug.log
    src
        main
            java
                com
                    mycompany
                        maven_viscount
                            MyJavaFX.java
                            SystemInfo.java
            image
                viscount.gif
            module-info.java
        test
    target
    nbactions.xml
    pom.xml

This is the contents of the debug.log file:
debug log open at C://temp/maven_viscount/image/debug.log

viscount picture at image/viscount.gif

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
        Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found


Check out How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application? and Where to put resource files in JavaFX.

And [tag:netbeans] has nothing to do with it.
